# CXFServlet throws java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.stax2.ri.EmptyIterator.getInstance()Lorg/codehaus/stax2/ri/EmptyIterator;

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf, stax

I'm using Java 11, Spring Boot 2.1.1 and Apache CXF 3.2.7 to expose a SOAP web service that imports an XSD schema. In the WSDL it shows like:

```
<wsdl:import location="http://localhost:9000/endpoint/ws?wsdl=WS_endpointSoapPort.wsdl" namespace="http://test.com"> </wsdl:import>
```

When I send a query it fails with the following stack:

```
2018-12-31 12:05:54,908 ERROR se.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[CXFServlet]: 175 - Servlet.service() for servlet [CXFServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.stax2.ri.EmptyIterator.getInstance()Lorg/codehaus/stax2/ri/EmptyIterator;
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After research in deeply, I found the following [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-7836) that mentions a problem with Stax2 version. BTW the ticket said that it resolves with the version that I'm using.

In the end, I fixed upgrading to woodstox-core-5.2.0. In fact, the library mentions a similar problem that was solved in that version. Details [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/woodstox/issues/46).

My current `mvn dependency:tree` is:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.11.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.11.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.23:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.9.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.9.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.9.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.13.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.1.1.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.1.1.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.1.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.11.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.23.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.9.5:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.9.5:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.1.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.6.2:test
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws:jar:3.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:3.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:jar:3.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:6.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-xml:jar:3.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-simple:jar:3.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-addr:jar:3.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-policy:jar:3.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:5.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:4.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:3.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.2.7:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-security:jar:3.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:jar:3.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-wsdl:jar:3.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:jar:3.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-security-saml:jar:3.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-security:jar:3.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.10.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-dom:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-common:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:jar:2.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.opensaml:opensaml-saml-impl:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-profile-api:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml-core:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |     \- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:4.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-saml-api:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-xmlsec-api:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml-soap-api:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-security-impl:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml-security-api:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |     +- org.cryptacular:cryptacular:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.54:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- org.opensaml:opensaml-xmlsec-impl:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- net.shibboleth.utilities:java-support:jar:7.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |     +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:19.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |     \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.10.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.opensaml:opensaml-xacml-impl:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml-xacml-api:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.opensaml:opensaml-xacml-saml-impl:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml-xacml-saml-api:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.jasypt:jasypt:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.geronimo.javamail:geronimo-javamail_1.4_mail:jar:1.8.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-policy:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.neethi:neethi:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-stax:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-bindings:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-ws-security-policy-stax:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-features-logging:jar:3.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.8.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.4.0-b180830.0438:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.4.0-b180830.0438:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.2.15:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt:pom:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.ws:jaxws-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.soap:javax.xml.soap-api:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.jws:javax.jws-api:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.ws:policy:jar:2.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.sun.activation:javax.activation:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.gmbal:gmbal-api-only:jar:3.1.0-b001:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.external:management-api:jar:3.0.0-b012:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.stream.buffer:streambuffer:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jvnet.mimepull:mimepull:jar:1.9.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.ha:ha-api:jar:3.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:jar:1.5.0:compile
[INFO] \- com.sun.xml.ws:rt:jar:2.3.1:compile
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to the apache jira [page](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-7836). I was able to resolve the issue by excluding the **woodstox-core-asl** which is the old version from **cxf-rt-ws-security** dependency.

Answer (score 9):

I had a conflict on the `org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api` which was included in version 3.1.4 within `org.apache.cxf:cxf-core` and in version 4.1 within `com.sun.xml.ws:rt`. I solved the conflict by removing the library using Maven excludes:

```
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
                <artifactId>stax2-api</artifactId><!-- 4.1 conflicts with 3.1.4 from apache cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws-->
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
```

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem and upgrading to CXF 3.2.7 or later fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Actually I only ran into this issue when upgrading to CXF 3.3.6 so it's worth digging deeper into the dependency tree.

Comment: Can confirm for 3.3.7

Answer (score 0):

The key is likely in your `mvn:dependency-tree` output. In my case:

```
[INFO]    \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-security:jar:3.3.6:compile
[INFO]       +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.3.6:compile
[INFO]       |  \- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:5.3.0:compile (version managed from 5.0.3)
[INFO]       |     \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:4.2:compile
[INFO]       \- org.apache.wss4j:wss4j-policy:jar:2.2.5:compile
[INFO]          \- org.apache.neethi:neethi:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO]             \- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.4.1:compile
[INFO]                \- (org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.2)
```

`org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-security:jar:3.3.6` leads to both version 3.1.4 and version 4.2 of stax2-api because of the very much outdated `woodstox-core-asl` dependency (from 2014). I will have to see if I can get rid of this, because it leads to the NoSuchMethodFoundError described above.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in new version of stax2-api new methods added. you can solve the problem by adding new version of the stax2-api. in my case adding

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
        <artifactId>stax2-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

solved the problem.

Answer (score -3):

This is the "jar hell problem".
You should use the exclusions clause that was mentioned Julien Kronegg.
Sorry for the previous answer that I have deleted.

Comment: This shouldn't never be done. You are adding twice the same artifact (only difference is the version) thus the classloader has access to both, but what is loaded is dependent on the classloader and it will usually only load 1 class of same signature. The fact that it behaves different for you and works/don't works is because the classloaders search for the class in different order.

Comment: Yes, Redlab, you are right, and this SHOULDN'T NEVER BE ONE. But it worked temporarily until ,,,, the migration from "javax" libraries to "jakarta" ones. That was a nightmare for me.